# Game of life in html and javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, conways-game-of-life

so i tried to write the Game of Life in html canvas and JavaScript and with the help of many online tutorials i managed to write some code i still believe in. But when I launch the html page in the browser and start the game itself (that is, i was able to pick the starting cells), the site slows down incredibly. I checked how far does the code make it with *console.log(...)*, so I found out it dies somewhere in the main loop. One thing I don't understand is that, when checking the values of some *for loop* variables, it seems like they are getting over the limit given in the *for*. Thank you for your help, it is possible I am missing something obvious.

```js
// variables etc.

var pGame = 0;
var sGame = 0;

const sc = 20;

const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
c.addEventListener("mousedown", fillPixel);

const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.scale(sc, sc); 

const columns = c.width / sc;
const rows = c.height / sc;

function createTable() {
 return new Array(columns).fill(null)
  .map(() => new Array(rows).fill(0));
}

var tableOne = createTable();
var tableTwo = createTable();

//functions

function fillPixel(event) {
 if (sGame == 0) {
  var x = Math.floor((event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft - 5) / sc);
  var y = Math.floor((event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop - 5) / sc);
  if (tableOne[x][y] == 0) {
   ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
   tableOne[x][y] = 1;
   console.log("filled x" + x + " y" + y);
  }else{
   ctx.clearRect(x, y, 1, 1);
   tableOne[x][y] = 0;
   console.log("cleared x" + x + " y" + y);
  }
 }
}

function pauseGame() {
 if (sGame == 1) {
  if (pGame == 0) {
   pGame = 1;
   document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = "resume";
  }else{
   pGame = 0;
   document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = "pause";
   startGame();
  }
 }
}

function resetGame(){
 sGame = 0;
 pGame = 0;
 document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = "pause";
 tableOne = createTable(); 
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function startGame() {
 sGame = 1;
 
 console.log("while");
 
 while (pGame == 0) { 
  
  tableOne = createTable();
  

  
  for (let col = 0; col < tableOne.length; col++){
  
   for (let row = 0; row < tableOne[col].length; row++){
    
    console.log("col" + col + " row" + row);
    
    const cell = tableOne[col][row];
    let neighbours = 0;



    for (let i = -1; i < 2; i++){

     for (let j = -1; j < 2; j++){


      if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
       continue;
      }
      
      const xCell = col + i;
      const yCell = row + j;
      
      if (xCell >= 0 && yCell >= 0 && xCell < 70 && yCell < 20) {
       neighbours += tableOne[xCell][yCell];
      }
     }
    }
    
    console.log("applying rules");
    
    if (cell == 1 && (neighbours == 2 || neighbours == 3)) {
     tableTwo[col][row] = 1;
    }else if (cell == 0 && neighbours == 3) {
     tableTwo[col][row] = 1;
    }
   }
  }
  
  console.log("drawing");
  
  tableOne = tableTwo.map(arr => [...arr]);
  tableTwo = createTable();
  for (let k = 0; k < tableOne.length; k++){
   for (let l = 0; l < tableOne[k]length; l++){
    if (tableOne[k][l] == 1) {
     ctx.fillRect(k, l, 1, 1);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #F1E19C;
 margin: 0;
}

.button {
 background-color: #2C786E;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#header {
 background-color: #2C786E;
 font-family: 'Times New Roman';
 padding: 10px 15px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 20px;
}

#footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 5px;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Roboto';
}

#canvas {
 border: 5px solid #813152;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display: block;
 cursor: crosshair
}

#btns {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="tres.css">
  </head>
  
  <body>
 <div id="header">
  <h1>Game of Life</h1>
 </div>
 
 <p>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1400" height="400"></canvas>
 </p>
 
 <p id="btns">
  <button class="button" onclick="startGame()"> start </button> 
  <button class="button" id="b1" onclick="pauseGame()"> pause </button>
  <button class="button" onclick="resetGame()"> clear </button>
 </p>
 
 <div id="footer">
  <p>&copy;2020</p>
 </div>
 <script src="dos.js"></script> 
  <body/>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say it's dying, is it because it's saying the page has become unresponsive or something like that? Could you post any errors you're receiving?

Comment: I do see a typo in your code `tableOne[k]length` should be `tableOne[k].length` which is probably the cause of your syntax error, but my answer is also relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Jacob pointed out you can't loop forever in JavaScript. JavaScript, in the browser, expects you to have code that responds to events and then exits so the browser can process more events. Events include the script loading, the page loading, timers, mouse events, keyboard events, touch events, network events etc..

So if you just do this

```js
for(;;);
```

The browser will freeze for 10 to 60 seconds and then tell you the page is unresponsive and ask if you want to kill it.

There are a bunch of ways to structure your code to deal with that.

- `setTimeout` which calls the a function later (or more specifically it "queues a task to add an event later since we said above the browser just processes events") or `setInterval` which calls a function at some interval.

  ```
  function processOneFrame() {
      ...
  }
  setInterval(processOneFrame, 1000); // call processOneFrame once a second
  ```

  or

  ```
  function processOneFrame() {
      ...
      setTimeout(processOneFrame, 1000); // call processOneFrame in a second
  }
  processOneFrame();
  ```
- Use `requestAnimationFrame`. This functions pretty similar to setTimeout except that it is aligned with the browser drawing the page and is generally called at the same speed as the your computer updates the screen, usually 60 times a second.

  ```
  function processOneFrame() {
      ...
      requestAnimationFrame(processOneFrame); // call processOneFrame for the next frame
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(processOneFrame);
  ```
- You can also use modern [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to still make your code looks like a normal loop

  ```
  // functions you can `await` on in an async function
  const waitFrame = _ => new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve));
  const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  async function main() {
     ...
     while (!done) {
        ... do game stuff...
        await waitFrame();
     }
  }
  ```

So, using that last method

- I changed `function startGame` to `async function startGame`. This way it is allowed to use the `await` keyword.
- At the top of `startGame` I check if it's already started. Otherwise every time we click start we`d start another.
- At the bottom of the `while (pGame == 0)` loop I put

  ```
  await wait(500);
  ```

  Which waits 1/2 a second between iterations. You can lower it if you want things to run faster or change it to `await waitFrame();` if you want to run at the 60 frames a second. For a small 70x20 field that seems a little too fast.
- I changed the mouse conversion code to more correctly compute a canvas relative mouse position.
- I fixed 2 typos of `tableOne[k]length` that needed to be `tableOne[k].length`
- At the top of the game loop the code was creating a new table. That meant the table being processed was always all 0s. So I got rid of that line.
- The code drawing the cells never cleared the canvas so I added a line to clear the canvas.
- I got rid of the magic numbers 70 and 20 when checking for out of bounds access
- I got rid of the start button. There is just a run/pause button and a clear button. I also got rid `sGame` and `pGame` and instead use `running` and `looping`. `looping` is true of the loop is still looping. `running` is whether or not it should run. Confusing I suppose but the issue is without these changes, if you press "run" then "pause" the loop inside startGame might still be at the `await` line (so the loop has no exited). If you were to press run again before the loop exits you'd start a second loop. So `looping` makes sure there is only one loop.
- Most importantly I removed all unnecessary code/css/html. You're supposed to make a **minimal** repo when asking for help.

```js
// variables etc.

let running = false;
let looping = false;

const sc = 20;

const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
c.addEventListener("mousedown", fillPixel);

const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.scale(sc, sc);

const columns = c.width / sc;
const rows = c.height / sc;

function createTable() {
  return new Array(columns).fill(null)
    .map(() => new Array(rows).fill(0));
}

var tableOne = createTable();
var tableTwo = createTable();

//functions

function fillPixel(event) {
  if (!running) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const canvasX = (event.clientX - rect.left) / rect.width * canvas.width;
    const canvasY = (event.clientY - rect.top) / rect.height * canvas.height;
    var x = Math.floor(canvasX / sc);
    var y = Math.floor(canvasY / sc);
    if (tableOne[x][y] == 0) {
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
      tableOne[x][y] = 1;
      //console.log("filled x" + x + " y" + y);
    } else {
      ctx.clearRect(x, y, 1, 1);
      tableOne[x][y] = 0;
      //console.log("cleared x" + x + " y" + y);
    }
  }
}

function pauseGame() {
  if (running) {
    running = false;
    document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = "run";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = "pause";
    startGame();
  }
}

function resetGame() {
  running = false;
  document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = "run";
  tableOne = createTable();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const waitFrame = _ => new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve));

async function startGame() {
  if (running || looping) {
    return; // it's already started
  }
  running = true;
  looping = true;

  console.log("while");

  while (running) {
    for (let col = 0; col < tableOne.length; col++) {
      for (let row = 0; row < tableOne[col].length; row++) {

        //console.log("col" + col + " row" + row);

        const cell = tableOne[col][row];
        let neighbours = 0;
        
        for (let i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
          for (let j = -1; j < 2; j++) {

            if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
              continue;
            }

            const xCell = col + i;
            const yCell = row + j;

            if (xCell >= 0 && yCell >= 0 && xCell < columns && yCell < rows) {
              neighbours += tableOne[xCell][yCell];
            }
          }
        }

        //console.log("applying rules");

        if (cell == 1 && (neighbours == 2 || neighbours == 3)) {
          tableTwo[col][row] = 1;
        } else if (cell == 0 && neighbours == 3) {
          tableTwo[col][row] = 1;
        }
      }
    }

    //console.log("drawing");

    tableOne = tableTwo.map(arr => [...arr]);
    tableTwo = createTable();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (let k = 0; k < tableOne.length; k++) {
      for (let l = 0; l < tableOne[k].length; l++) {
        if (tableOne[k][l] == 1) {
          ctx.fillRect(k, l, 1, 1);
        }
      }
    }
    await wait(500); // wait 1/2 a second (500 milliseconds)
  }
  looping = false;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F1E19C;
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  background-color: #2C786E;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#canvas {
  border: 5px solid #813152;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  cursor: crosshair
}

#btns {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1400" height="400"></canvas>
</p>

<p id="btns">
  <button class="button" id="b1" onclick="pauseGame()"> run </button>
  <button class="button" onclick="resetGame()"> clear </button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you have to keep in mind with JavaScript is that it's a single-threaded language. What's more, when any JavaScript code is running, any interactivity on the page becomes impossible. JavaScript in a browser is mainly meant to be *event* driven, where you execute small pieces of code at a time then go idle; then, when an event takes place (button click, timer, HTTP response), you execute the handler for that event.

Constantly running code, like your game loop, won't work right. Although you have a variable to stop the loop, none of your event code like the button clicks will be able to run because the single JavaScript thread will never yield control back to the DOM.

What you'll want to do is convert your while loop to something event driven. One approach is to set periodic timers and then do the game updates on each tick. One approach I prefer is to use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). Your while loop can become this instead:

```
function startGame() {
  sGame = 1;
  requestAnimationFrame(performUpdates);
}

function performUpdates() {
  tableOne = createTable();
  for (let col = 0; col < tableOne.length; col++){
    // ...
  }

  // ...

  if (sGame && !pGame) {
    requestAnimationFrame(performUpdates);
  }
}
```

After a call to `performUpdates` completes, JavaScript will sit idle for a while, allowing your page the ability to respond to click events. Since at the end you've requested another animation frame, when your browser decides it makes sense, `performUpdates` will be called again, and you'll get your next cycle.

Comment: you can use `const waitFrame = _ => new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve));` and then you can use a loop `async function doGame() { while(!exit) { ... do stuff...; await waitFrame(); } }`;